# Is there an aspect of the person that is outside time and or size? Does anyone argue that to defeat nihilism?

Tags: time, nihilism, values, individualism

Is there an aspect of the person that is outside time or scale? Does anyone argue that to defeat nihilism, and does that come up in discussing value nihilism?

I just think that *anyone* who claims that **nothing matters** unless it has meaningful, valuable, effects in relation with others, is irreversibly committed to meaningless nihilism.

Unless there is an aspect of the person that is outside time. Or perhaps one to which the scale or magnitude of "meaning" doesn't matter.

I was just hoping that, for those who would not change the course of history, some aspect of the individual exists the same independent of whether it is everything or hardly anything at all. What is the word for that? What is it?

Comment: It may be the aspect of our being (i.e. our intellect) that can instinctively identify and merge with the mind of God without any sense of rebelliousness, rejection, or denial. In other words, without reservation or reticence. Intrinsic divine nature, perhaps. Sometimes called divinization or theosis.

Comment: interesting comment thanks @Bread but i'd prefer an atheist response...

Comment: Not atheists, but what you ask for sounds suspiciously like Kant's argument for a *causa noumenon*, i.e. an intellectual part of the self that exists outside the restrictions of the sensible world, especially outside time.

Comment: I don't think you're correct to see Bread's response as theistic, The view you're asking about is well-known as the Perennial philosophy. Time and size would be aspects of the mundane world of relativity. The Real would not be extended in time or space. The Real would our origin and probably the 'aspect' you're talking about. For further information there is more literature than anyone would have time to read, and endless personal testimony. .    .  .

Comment: sorry, @PeterJ not familiar with it, only what i would read into certain theists.

Comment: Even aside from the fact that it is hard to detect connections between paragraphs, each paragraph contains hard to interpret expressions. What are "meaningful, valuable, effects in relation with others", with other people? What does this have to do with time and scale(?)? The word "nihilism" seem to appear out of nowhere. What is the "magnitude of "meaning""? What does "it" in  "independent of whether it is everything or hardly anything at all" refer to?

Comment: everyone else seemed to understand @Conifold i can't explain every word!

Comment: I read the comments and the answer, they seem to talk about their favorite things on a loose association rather than about what you are asking. My own association was that one needs some atemporal personality for moral realism, with nihilism as a foil. But for substantive answers, if you are interested, a better strategy is to present one finished thought/concern at a time rather than a string of vague unfinished ones. People are moved more by a question when it is less of a recognizing contours in a cloud.

Comment: agreed there is a lack of context, it is too practical (IMHO) a question to generate a specific good answer. but it makes sense! just broad

Answer (score 1):

“Self and other (both creations of the mind) have no ultimate existence, but you can’t use those words, self and other, to describe the Buddha Nature. It is wondrously beyond the mind and therefore beyond the notion of time and space that the mind creates."

David Smith - A Record of Awakening- Practice and Insight on the Buddhist Path

Comment: not a bad answer, but one would prefer an analysis of why we might believe that, on this stackexchange

Comment: @confused - Feel free to believe what you like. This just notes what meditators say about these things.

Comment: @user35983 - On reflection I see you're right. And I seem to have confused you with 'confused' for some reason lost in time.